# How can I change Tomcat version of a war in Spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I've created a spring project with Maven. I would like to change the version of embedded tomcat.

How should I modify pom.xml or s/t?

pom.xml :

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <tomcat.version>8.5</tomcat.version>
</properties>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xxxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyyy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>xxxxx</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.0</tomcat.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: First question: Why would you like to change the tomcat version?

Comment: You need to override the properties set in spring's parent pom.

Comment: Error  creating bean with name"'tomcarservletwebserverFactory"

Comment: ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:175)

Comment: How can I override parent.xml?